# UWP C# get grid of item clicked

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a list of images and I then make a grid and insert an image, and 2 text, so the grid looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------
|    | Text 1
|    |   Text 2
-----------------------------------
```

These grids are just stacked ontop of each other.

Code to make grids:

```
img = new Image();
            img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, "/Assets/test/Images/test.png"));
            img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            img.Width = 30;
            img.Height = 30;

            username = new TextBlock();
            username.Name = "1"
            username.Tapped += "tapped_func";
            username.Text = "Text 1";
            username.FontSize = 24;

            txt = new TextBlock();
            txt.Text = "Text 2";
            txt.FontSize = 14;

            var grid_item = new Grid();

            RowDefinition r0 = new RowDefinition();
            r0.Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
            RowDefinition r1 = new RowDefinition();
            r1.Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);

            ColumnDefinition c0 = new ColumnDefinition();
            c0.Width = new GridLength(.50, GridUnitType.Star);

            ColumnDefinition c1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            c1.Width = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star);

            grid_item.Margin = new Thickness(10);

            grid_item.RowDefinitions.Add(r0);
            grid_item.RowDefinitions.Add(r1);
            grid_item.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c0);
            grid_item.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);

            Grid.SetColumn(img, 0);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(img, 2);

            Grid.SetColumn(username, 1);

            Grid.SetColumn(txt, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(txt, 1);

            grid_item.Children.Add(img);
            grid_item.Children.Add(username);
            grid_item.Children.Add(txt);
```

The image is on the left side and the 2 textblocks are on the right. Currently I set the ID of the image to text 1's name and then when the user clicks on Text 1, I can download the image.

Is there a way so if the user clicks on the grid, text1, or text2 it will call the function? I was thinking of

```
Username.Parent
```

but I don't know what 'Parent' does exactly, will it get the Grid?

Comment: Yeah, using `username.Parent` will get the `Grid`, but I'm not sure where you want to use this and when you say "call the function", which "function" do you mean? Do you want to get the `Grid` in `username.Tapped` event?

Comment: @Jay Zuo - MSFT I forgot to include a function to download the image and all that, that's what I referred to. And I do want to get the grid in the username.Tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing the hard way to handle this senario.

For me, I would create a List, bind the list to a list view with item template similar to your layout. The Item object will hold the ID of image.

Then, I handle the click event of the Grid (so wherever user tapped, the handler will be fired), I get the sender object, get the DataContext of the sender (the Item binded to the ListViewItem). Download the image using the ID in the Item.

Comment: Do you have some code? I have honestly haven't used a ListView before (can I have the image, and two textboxes in it?)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thang2410199/37a07798c9165d6cfb3c

Create DataContext for the listview, which have ObservableCollect<Item> ListItem. Item has ImageSource, Text1 and Text2 property.